# Raspbian log in and password problem

Tags: login, password

What is the Raspbian login (word required first time)

ask password:  what password is required to enter?  Because it asks for a password the keyboard stops working again tty question will appear for Raspbian, if I press alt F2 or F1 again it will look for login and looks for password.

Please can you help me?

Comment: the default password is something that a simple search would've uncovered for you! As for alt F2 etc - these are accessing virtual terminals, linux usually has 6 of them (altF1 to altF6). The keyboard doesn't stop working when you enter a password, the password simply isn't "echoed" back to the screen while you type it (it's called security) - perhaps it'd be simpler for you to have your pi automatically log in for you - this can be set up in `raspi-config`

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default user is `pi` and the default password is `raspberry`.

The password will not be echoed.